# How do I create two objects, of two different classes, with one form and 'new' action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, polymorphic-associations

I am building an app in which the users can have different roles (like seller, buyer, agency, etc). So my plan is use polymorphic association, build a class for each of the roles, and associate each instance with one user account. Each user can only be of one of those types, and after reading on the subject I concluded that this is better than using STI, but correct me if I am wrong.

So the app will have different sign up screens for the main types of user accounts. For instance, in the Seller sign up form, what will happen is that the user will fill in the details required for his user account and the fields specific for the Seller profile.

So this form should create the user object, and then the seller object associated to the former. How do you handle this? My guess is that this form should correspond to the 'new' action of the sellers controller, and in the create action the user account should be created before finally creating the seller.

Is this correct? If so, should I call the User controller create action from the Seller controller, or call directly the User model? If it's the former please provide some example code, because I am not sure about how I should call one controller from another.

EDIT: I also considered using a multipart form, which is probably easier, but before deciding I want to check out this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're bent on doing it this way, I'd say just call the model from the create method of the Seller controller. What type of relationship do you have between the User model and the Seller model? Because you'd need to do something like this:

```
def create
    user = User.create(params[:user])
    seller = Seller.new(params[:seller])
    seller.user_id = user.id
    seller.save
    redirect_to #wherever
end
```

Here I just assumed you have a `belongs_to :user` in the Seller model. Still I would advise you to consider a gem like cancan or something to handle roles instead of this approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Isn't the problem beyond authorization, though? @oalo uses the term "role," but really it sounds like it's a `Profile`. If that is the case, I think there is reason to use a polymorphic association between `User` and `Profile`, where a User `belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true`.

Comment: Yes, @Matt, I should have said profiles, its much more precise. Sellers and regular user's profiles will differ a lot and have lots of different fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested form.  A user has one role.  You can view this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1, it explained how to use nested form.  You will be calling User controller when will create User and Role.

Comment: I had a similar application design as @oalo and unfortunately it seems really hacky to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with a polymorphic assocation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach for this question.  Have one roles class.  Then create methods in the user class like.

```
def can_assign_users?
  roles.map(&:name).includes('admin')
end
```

You might have 50 models in a few years otherwise.  Plus there a plenty of gems that work like this so you can leverage them.

Comment: How would I handle the extra columns, methods and views for the different roles then? This sounds more complicated too me, specially since I will have two, at most three different user types. What odo you think in that case?